# C programming error if statement

Tags: c, if-statement

i have this program and it's working fine until the very end. When I ask the user if he/she wants to do a discount and the user enters y/n, the program just halts and doesn't go to the if statement. Any help? Thanks :)

```
int calculate(){

printf("Do you want to make a discount? y/n \n");
scanf("%c",&ask);

if (ask == 'y')
{
    printf("Enter the actual money that you want to make a discount\n");
    scanf("%f",&disc);
    discount= (total * (disc/100));
    net= (total - discount);
    printf("The total bill is: %.2f\n", net);


}
else
if(ask == 'n')
{
        printf("The total bill is: %.2f\n", total);


    }
//menu();
return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this

```
scanf("%c",&ask);
```

to

```
scanf(" %c",&ask);
```

to explicitly ignore any left over white space.